# Textfield overlapping with UIView's text on keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am working on iOS application and in one of the view I have to load user comments as well as let them post comments. Everything looked fine until keyboard appears on user taps on text field to enter comments. The text on the UIView is overlapping with textfield as shown below.

[image]

Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS it is customary to add all view elements within a keyboard-enabled view into a UIScrollView. This way, when the keyboard slides up - the other elements slide up with it to avoid being obstructed.

Lucky for you, someone has implemented a UIScrollView that avoids the keyboard automatically, so all you need is to insert your view elements in to one of these and everything should work perfectly.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: I am currently building UIlabels dynamically and binding them to the UISCrollView dynamically. However, seems like TPKeyboardAvoiding takes care of things that are statically binded to the UIScrollView. Is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Don't use UIScrollView, use the provided subclass. I'm not sure I get the problem

Comment: the problem is the issue mentioned before still exists. I am dynamically adding the comments to the TPKeyboardAvoiding class of type UIScrollView.When I do that, if I add more than 4 comments, it's overlapping with the textfield, which is part of TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the UITextField and UIButton("Post") move up when the user taps on the textField you should move everything else above it up an equal distance at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

With more than just a little bit of text on the screen, you will have to go with UIScrollView. You can then use the `[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, offset) animated:YES];` to move up (or down) your text in relation to the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inputAccessoryView` for your post button and `UITextField`.
Like this:

```
-(void)addAccessoryViewOnTextView
{
    UIToolbar *keyboardHeaderView = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 39)];

    keyboardHeaderView.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    /* Here use your post button and textfield.
    UIBarButtonItem *nextBtn= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(nextEvent:)];
     UIBarButtonItem *prevBtn= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(prevEvent:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneEvent:)];*/

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [keyboardHeaderView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: doneBtn,flexibleSpace,prevBtn, nextBtn, nil]];

    [yourTextField setInputAccessoryView:keyboardHeaderView];
    keyboardHeaderView = nil;

}
```

> And call this method in `viewDidLoad` or anywhere your `UITextField` initializes.